# Fancybox won't open the second time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fancybox

When i close my fancybox and then want to open it again nothing happens. It has something to do with the GET. The fancybox needs the **CourseID** to edit the course info and so does the **CourseProfile** page to show the course info. I used **GET** to do this. I think somehow it won't get the courseid after the fancybox closes. It works perfectly the first time. My CourseProfile page is like this:

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_GET['courseid'])){
    $courseid = $_GET['courseid'];
}else{
    $courseid = 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="Edit" href="EditCourse.php?CourseID=<?php echo $courseid; ?>">Edit</a>
```

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
$(".Edit").fancybox();
```

Comment: it seems like a js error was triggered after you open it for the first time so it won't work for the second (in this case, EditCourse.php is being loaded as ajax content so make sure it's not including additional and conflicting js or jQuery files/scripts into the main page.) Eventually, you may prefer to open this files as iframe content to avoid conflicts with the existing page

Comment: Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'width' of undefined
it's from the fancybox script. Did i forget to declare anything?

Comment: well, try setting `width` inside your custom script for testing purposes like `$(".Edit").fancybox({width: 400})`

Comment: Problem solved. I included jquery and fancybox also in the EditCourse.php file(sorry I didn't notice at first). Thanks!